# Responsive input text size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

From my understanding, the `width` of the element rendered by `input` tag with `type` attribute as `text` is decided by its size. (the other factor being the dimensions of the font active at that DOM node).

Without changing anything about the font, is it possible adjust the `size` attribute of the `input` tag "responsively", using only CSS?

The effect I'm looking to achieve is that for certain screen width's have the input size be, say, 20, and for others, I'd like it to be, say, 40.

I know the JS solutions. A no answer would be better than a JS solution. Thank you.

EDIT: Some more information, and in light of which my question might be a little too specific but I figured I'll ask anyway- the reason why I'm asking for it is because I'm using bootstrap with feedback icon. When I set width to 200% based on a certain screen-size, the feedback icon stays at its current position, I could change that but I'm not comfortable with that solution. Would anyone know why the feedback icon doesn't move appropriately?

Answer (score 2):

Making measurement with **%** and **em** will make your elements responsive

```
e.g. input { width: 100%; padding: .5em 1em; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It feels hackish, but you can set a font-size based on `vw` horizontal units. However, that will only constrain the width exactly for monospace webfonts (where you know how the ratio of width to height of the letters is).

```css
      body {
      font-size: 14px; /*fallback for old browsers */
      font-size: calc(1.4*100vw/80);
      /* 1.4 is a fudge factor by inspection. */
      }
```

```html
<body>
1234567890
    1234567890
    1234567890
    1234567890
    1234567890
    1234567890
    1234567890
    1234567890
</body>
```